# check if client can access the page, if not do something

Tags: php, http-headers, cdn

I'm working on "CDN" video delivery script. my problem is not all providers are included, therefor I need to check if the client can access the link, if not send him another one.
i've tried with get_headers, but with get_headers only the server checks if it can access the link, not the user.

```
$header = get_headers($VIDEO);
preg_match('/\d{3}/', $header[0], $code);
if($code[0] < 400){
        header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
        header("Location:" . $VIDEO . $dop);
}else{
        header("Content-type: video/x-flv");
        header("X-Accel-Redirect: /".$_GET["filename"].$dop);
}
```

Comment: If I understood your question you need to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get users IP address.

Comment: Why not use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ?

Comment: IP is in $_SERVER, client details OR reference should be in $_SESSION or $_COOKIE (whatever you used)

Comment: how do i check with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] if user can access the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$ip_address = array('50.101.20.212', '25.65.659.25');
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip_address )){
    // may access site;
}else{
    // access denied
}
```

**UPDATE**

You may do the opposite way to find out whether the user may enter the link or not,

```
$ip_address = array('50.101.20.212', '25.65.659.25');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $ip_address )){
     //access denied
}
```

Comment: i'm not trying to figure out users ip. i want to know if the user can access a "link".

Comment: *UPDATE* it's bad solution. i need list of all ip address that can access the server...